# Create the <li> for <ul> dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to add <li> items dynamically, based on their value, to an unordered list (<ul>). How do I do that programatically?

Comment: Are you writing things to the Console or are you using Asp.Net and need to create controls dynamically?

Comment: Can you give more details? Some code? Is this ASP.NET? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: be more specific, please

Comment: i am using the ASP.Net this will be useful for me for creating the <li> items based on the values retreived from database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any specifics, here is how you might bind an array of strings to a repeater. This is using the web form ASP.NET model.

```
<asp:Repeater id="unorderedList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="unorderedList_ItemDataBound">
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <ul>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
          <li><asp:Literal id="myItem" runat="server" /></li>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
       </ul>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

...

```
private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] array = { "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry" };
    unorderedList.DataSource = array;
    unorderedList.DataBind();
}

protected void unorderedList_ItemDataBound(object sender,  RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    {
        string itemValue = (string)e.Item.DataItem;
        Literal myItem = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("myItem");
        myItem.Text = itemValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I won't DV this answer because it is being correct however a ListView would be much more suited for this.